# What is measure of angle $CED.$

Tags: geometry

In the figure, $ABCD$ is a rhombus with area $48\sqrt 3 cm^2,$ $|DE|=10cm, |BE|=2cm.$ What is the measure of the angle $\angle CED?$ Please help me. Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

$$S(ABCD)=\frac{AC \cdot BD}{2} \Rightarrow 48\sqrt{3}=\frac{AC \cdot 12}{2} \Rightarrow AC=8\sqrt{3}$$

Futhermore, let be $I$ the intersection bettwen $AC$ and $BD$ then $CI=4\sqrt{3}$ and $AC$ is perpendicular to $BD$ so the triangle $EIC$ is such that $\angle CIE=90°$.

$$\tan(\angle CEI)=\frac{CI}{EI}=\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{4}=\sqrt{3} \Rightarrow \angle CEI=\angle CED =60° $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be the angle $\angle CED$. We can get $AC$ by means the area formula:

$${AC\cdot BD\over 2}=48\sqrt3$$
$$AC={2\cdot48\sqrt3\over12}=8\sqrt3$$

If $M$ is the center of the rhombus $CM=4\sqrt3$; $ME=MB-BE=6-2=4$ so:

$$\tan\alpha={CM\over ME}=\sqrt3$$

hence $\alpha=60$.